# Show that $f$ =constant $\mu\times \nu$-almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have no idea about the following problem. Could you please give a hint? Thank you very much for your help.
Let $(X,m,\mu)$ and $(Y,n,\nu)$ be $\sigma-$finite measure spaces, and let $f: X\times Y\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function. 
a, Assume that the function $f_x$ is $\nu$-almost everywhere constant for $\mu-$almost every $x\in X$, and the function $f^y$ is $\mu-$almost everywhere constant for $\nu$-almost every $y\in Y$. Show that $f$ is $\mu\times \nu$-almost everywhere constant.
b, Assume that $f\in L^1(\mu\times\nu)$ and $\int\limits_{E\times F}fd(\mu\times\nu)=0$ whenever $E\in m,\ F\in n$, and $\mu\times \nu (E\times F)<\infty$. Show that $f=0$ $\mu\times \nu$-almost everywhere.

Comment: Have you heard of Fubini's theorem?

Comment: @3-in-441: I know. could you give me more detail about how to apply it here?

Comment: I am curious how Fubini helps for a.